# How to create a table with NaNs in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to create a table that is 10 x 5 with only NaNs. I start by creating an array with NaNs:

```
N = NaN(10, 5);
```

then I try converting it to a table:

```
T = table(N);
```

It puts all cells into one column, but I need the table to be 5 columns with one NaN in each cell. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`array2table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/array2table.html) 
 works just fine.  This takes a matrix and converts it to the `table` structure where each column of the matrix is a column in the output table:

```
>> N = NaN(10, 5);
>> T = array2table(N)

T = 

    N1     N2     N3     N4     N5 
    ___    ___    ___    ___    ___

    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 5):

What you want is:

```
t = array2table(NaN(10,5))
```

Bonus (so our answers are slightly different :P) You can rename the variables to anything you want with something like:

```
t.Properties.VariableNames = {'x1','x2','x3','x4','x5'};
```

Comment: Hahaha looks like we're on the same wavelength Matthew. We were 5 seconds away from each other +1.

Comment: I am unsure where to add my comment. The accepted answer or this one. But as the question was not about renaming, my comment is more appropriate for the Bonus-Tip :-): The array2table function directly supports "VariableNames" as a keyword argument. So the naming can be provided directly in one go.